# Migrate From DevArt UniDac To FireDac

Tags: delphi, migration, firedac, unidac

I've been using UniDac for 2 years now and it was the best solution for me, but because it doesn't support Asynch query's i have to move on to FireDac is there any quick migration wizard or something that i can use because i have around 200+ TUniStoredProc components in my form and i would like to convert them to TFDStoredProc, doing every one of them by hand would take allot of time, and that i dont have, I would like to replace them the old TUniStoredProc with the TFDStoredProc

my setup:

Embarcadero Rad Studio XE5

the components are connected to MSSQL database

Comment: I have no experience with UniDac, but I've migrated FIB+ to FireDac some time ago: I've created interpose objects to mimic FIB+ components and then used ADDFMChanger utility. Perhaps you could get some inspiration from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620795/proven-recommended-way-to-migrate-application-from-fib-to-fire-dac-components)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sollution ** Warning not perfect, ant may cause **DataBinding** loss to opened forms ** so please recheck all databindings once finished also have a backup just in case.

1. Download and install NotePad++
2. Install it and open it press CTRL+SHIFT+F select find in files
3. Find What: TUniStoredProc Replace with: TFDStoredProc Filters:
   *.pas;*.dfm Directory: you project directory
4. press **Replace In Files**
5. Find What: TUniConnection Replace with: TFDConnection Filters:
       *.pas;*.dfm Directory: you project directory
6. press **Replace In Files**
7. Find What: ;1 Replace with: (leave empty) Filters:
           *.dfm Directory: you project directory
8. press **Replace In Files**
9. Open Delphi, then Open the project it will give you some errors
   about not finding properties press ignore all
10. check all the settings of Connections and DataBindings then
     recompile

i tried the AnyDac addon which would basically to the same but you would need to generate a rule text file for UniDac, this is the best one i have right now if you come up with a better one i will accept that answer.